# How to create a separate environment using ArcGIS Pro Python in Visual Studio

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-pro, visual-studio

I am switching from Pycharm to Visual Studio as my Python script IDE.

I have been trying to create an environment for ArcGIS Pro but I had no success so far.

I can create Custom Environment from the existing environments but it directly uses the environment for ArcGIS Pro.

I would rather use the ArcGIS Pro Python (3.6) as a base interpreter and create a separate environment.

Anyone has the same problem or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203380/setting-up-python-arcpy-with-arcgis-pro-and-visual-studio/203381?noredirect=1#comment577470_203381

Comment: @Midavalo thank you for your comment but I already found this. This method uses the environment comes with ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I do for Visual Studio *Code* and it works out pretty well for me. I use this code in a `.cmd` file to create a conda environment for my project, based off of the `arcgispro-py3` environment. This will mirror that environment, so `arcpy` will work (change paths and venv names accordingly - I use a custom place to store my venvs so I really know where they all are):

```
cd "C:\sw\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\Scripts"
call activate root
call conda create --clone arcgispro-py3 --prefix c:/sw/conda-envs/traffic-incidents
call activate c:/sw/conda-envs/traffic-incidents
call conda install -y pyodbc
```

Next, tell Visual Studio Code where to look for the venvs. In `settings.json`, add/set `python.venvPath` to where your conda envs live:

```
"python.venvPath": "C:\\sw\\conda-envs"
```

For Visual Studio, once you have created your env you can set the Python env much like you can in PyCharm in the settings. See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) for more on that. Much like in PyCharm, you can also create environments directly in the Visual Studio interface.