# ArcGIS Pro Python Interpreter Setup with Visual Studio Code

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-pro, visual-studio-code

I'm fairly new to Stack Exchange and not very well-versed in IDE's.  I'm struggling to set up the ArcGIS Pro Python interpreter with Visual Studio Code.  I have ArcGIS Pro 2.4.3 and VSC 1.44.2.  I'm trying to follow the advice on the below thread, but I cannot ask questions in that thread, only add answers.

[Original Thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203380/setting-up-python-arcpy-with-arcgis-pro-and-visual-studio)

So here's my question.  I cannot find the ""+ Custom..." and select "Configure" location where I add the Python interpreter, as mentioned in the thread above.  In VSC I can go ctrl+Shift+P and it shows me the current Python interpreters that the program already knows, but I cannot add a new location.  In File-->Preferences-->Settings under Workspace I can search for Python and there are 147 settings for Python.

[image: Python Settings]

I tried adding the C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\python.exe path under Python Path and adding C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3 under Pipenv Path but this hasn't changed anything in terms of the program understanding that I'm trying to add a new Python interpreter option.

There are so many settings for Python I don't even know where to start or if I am even changing the right settings.  It's not very intuitive.  Please help!

Answer (score 8):

There are a few different ways you can get VS Code to work with ArcGIS Pro Python. I'm not going to list them all, just the way I've started using for every thing I do.

1. Make sure you have the Python extension for VS Code installed from the Marketplace
2. Press CTRL + , (comma) to open the settings. From here if you type `pythonpath` it'll filter down to some Python specific places under your **User** settings. Update the following (if the path I used below doesn't match, update as needed)

**Python > Auto Complete > Typeshed Paths** : `C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python/envs/arcgispro-py3/python.exe`

**Python > Jedi Path** : `C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python/envs/arcgispro-py3/python.exe`
**NOTE** -- If Intellisense (code-complete) doesn't seem to work, remove this setting, re-start VS Code and try again.

**Python > Python Path** : `C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python/envs/arcgispro-py3/python.exe`

3. Finally, I do all my development in a specific folder, generally new to whatever I'm working on. Inside that folder I have the VS Code recognized folder of `.vscode`. Inside that folder are two files (depending how you setup, they'd be auto-created, but I just copy/paste these files from previous projects to quick-start). See the contents below for `settings.json` and `launch.json`.
4. When you start VS Code, make sure you **Open Folder** or **Open Workspace**, not just the file `.py` file you're working on. That way Code knows about the `.vscode` directory and it's contents.

**settings.json**

```
  {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python/envs/arcgispro-py3/python.exe",
            //"pythonPath": "C:/Users/khibma/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe", 
            //"pythonPath": C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.5/python.exe",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Terminal (integrated)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ok, I added the above paths and copied your json settings, modifying the paths to reflect my own computer directory settings.  In the bottom left-hand corner it now says Python 3.6.8 64-bit, so it did something.  However, when I type import arcpy into the Python shell in the terminal window I still get the "no module named arcpy".  Why is this the case?

Comment: At the terminal window you dont have access to arcpy because the terminal is using the system path, not a path from Code itself. And you do not have a reference within your system Path to ArcGIS Pro conda's Python. If its loading up some Python, odds are it is not a Python version associated with ArcGIS. If you type `path` at the prompt, you should be able to see where it's finding Python from.

Comment: Ah I see, so there's no way to change the source path for the terminal?  Is this the case with all IDE programs?  If this is the case, I suppose using the built-in Python shell within ArcGIS Pro is the best way to test segments of arcpy code?

Comment: You could set your system Path and re-start VS Code. That should do it

Comment: How do I set the System Path? Would the System Path also be C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/Pro/bin/Python/envs/arcgispro-py3/python.exe?

Comment: It took some experimenting to get the `.vscode/settings.json` file to be created for me. What worked: _File >> Open Folder >> {d:/code/my-project}_ and then opening _Settings_ and clicking [Workspace] tab, and changing something. https://i.imgur.com/ajqekqS.png